# How to access DVC-controlled files from Oracle?

Tags: python, oracle, dvc

I have been storing my large files in CLOBs within Oracle, but I am thinking of storing my large files in a shared drive, then having a column in Oracle contain pointers to the files. This would use DVC.

When I do this,

(a) are the paths in Oracle paths that point to the files in my shared drive, as in, the actual files themselves?

(b) or do the paths in Oracle point somehow to the DVC metafile?

Any insight would help me out!

Thanks :)
Justin

---

EDIT to provide more clarity:

I checked here (https://dvc.org/doc/api-reference/open), and it helped, but I'm not fully there yet ...

I want to pull a file from a remote dvc repository using python (which I have connected to the Oracle database). So, if we can make that work, I think I will be good. But, I am confused. If I specify 'remote' below, then how do I name the file (e.g., 'activity.log') when the remote files are all encoded?

```
with dvc.api.open(
        'activity.log',
        repo='location/of/dvc/project',
        remote='my-s3-bucket'
        ) as fd:
    for line in fd:
        match = re.search(r'user=(\w+)', line)
        # ... Process users activity log
```

(NOTE: For testing purposes, my "remote" DVC directory is just another folder on my MacBook.)

I feel like I'm missing a key concept about getting remote files ...

I hope that adds more clarity. Any help figuring out remote file access is appreciated! :)

Justin

---

EDIT to get insights on 'rev' parameter:

Before my question, some background/my setup:
(a) I have a repo on my MacBook called 'basics'.
(b) I copied into 'basics' a directory of 501 files (called 'surface_files') that I subsequently pushed to a remote storage folder called 'gss'. After the push, 'gss' contains 220 hash directories.

The steps I used to get here are as follows:

```
> cd ~/Desktop/Work/basics
> git init
> dvc init
> dvc add ~/Desktop/Work/basics/surface_files
> git add .gitignore surface_files.dvc
> git commit -m "Add raw data"
> dvc remote add -d remote_storage ~/Desktop/Work/gss
> git commit .dvc/config -m "Configure remote storage"
> dvc push
> rm -rf ./.dvc/cache
> rm -rf ./surface_files
```

Next, I ran the following Python code to take one of my surface files, named `surface_100141.dat`, and used `dvc.api.get_url()` to get the corresponding remote storage file name. I then copied this remote storage file into my desktop under the file's original name, i.e., `surface_100141.dat`.

The code that does all this is as follows, but FIRST, MY QUESTION --- when I run the code as it is shown below, no problems; but when I uncomment the 'rev=' line, it fails. I am not sure why this is happening. I used `git log` and `cat .git/refs/heads/master` to make sure that I was getting the right hash. WHY IS THIS FAILING? That is my question.

(In full disclosure, my git knowledge is not too strong yet. I'm getting there, but it's still a work in progress! :))

```
import dvc.api
import os.path
from os import path
import shutil

filename = 'surface_100141.dat' # This file name would be stored in my Oracle database
home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')+'/' # This simply expanding '~' into '/Users/ricej/'

resource_url = dvc.api.get_url(
    path=f'surface_files/{filename}', # Works when 'surface_files.dvc' exists, even when 'surface_files' directory and .dvc/cache do not
    repo=f'{home_dir}Desktop/Work/basics',
    # rev='5c92710e68c045d75865fa24f1b56a0a486a8a45', # Commit hash, found using 'git log' or 'cat .git/refs/heads/master'
    remote='remote_storage')
resource_url = home_dir+resource_url
print(f'Remote file: {resource_url}')

new_dir = f'{home_dir}Desktop/' # Will copy fetched file to desktop, for demonstration
new_file = new_dir+filename
print(f'Remote file copy: {new_file}')

if path.exists(new_file):
    os.remove(new_file)
    
dest = shutil.copy(resource_url, new_file) # Check your desktop after this to see remote file copy
```

Comment: Files would normally be stored in a `BLOB` column not a `CLOB` column unless the files are purely text that won't be impacted by things like character set conversion if the client happens to request a different character set than the database.  When you say that you're considering storing pointers to the files, are you talking about a `BFILE` column (which is just a reference to a file system path)?  Or are you talking about a `VARCHAR2` column where you are storing a string of the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand the question (it would be great to expand it a bit on the actual use case you are trying to solve with this database), but I can share a few thoughts.

When we talk about DVC, I think you need to specify a few things to identify the file/directory:

1. Git commit + path (actual path like `data/data/xml`). Commit (or to be precise any Git revision) is needed to identify the version of the data file.
2. Or path in the DVC storage (`/mnt/shared/storage/00/198493ef2343ao` ...`) + actual name of this file. This way you would be saving info that` .dvc` files have.

I would say that second way is *not* recommended since to some extent it's an implementation detail - how does DVC store files internally. The public interface to DVC organized data storage is its repository URL + commit + file name.

Edit (example):

```py
with dvc.api.open(
        'activity.log',
        repo='location/of/dvc/project',
        remote='my-s3-bucket'
        ) as fd:
    for line in fd:
        match = re.search(r'user=(\w+)', line)
        # ... Process users activity log
```

`location/of/dvc/project` this path must point to an actual Git repo. This repo should have a `.dvc` or `dvc.lock` file that has `activity.log` name in it + its hash in the remote storage:

```yaml
outs:
  - md5: a304afb96060aad90176268345e10355
    path: activity.log
```

By reading this Git repo and analyzing let's say `activity.log.dvc` DVC will be able to create the right path `s3://my-bucket/storage/a3/04afb96060aad90176268345e10355`

`remote='my-s3-bucket'` argument is optional. By default it will use the one that is defined in the repo itself.

Let's take another real example:

```py
with dvc.api.open(
        'get-started/data.xml',
        repo='https://github.com/iterative/dataset-registry'
        ) as fd:
    for line in fd:
        match = re.search(r'user=(\w+)', line)
        # ... Process users activity log
```

In the `https://github.com/iterative/dataset-registry` you could find the [`.dvc` file](https://github.com/iterative/dataset-registry/blob/master/get-started/data.xml.dvc) that is enough for DVC to create a path to the file by also analyzing its [config](https://github.com/iterative/dataset-registry/blob/master/.dvc/config)

```
https://remote.dvc.org/dataset-registry/a3/04afb96060aad90176268345e10355
```

you could run `wget` on this file to download it

Comment: Thanks, @Shcheklein :) See my edit above providing more detail :)

Comment: @Justin thanks! I've updated the answer with some details. Please let me know if it's still not clear and you need more info.

Comment: Thanks again, @Shcheklein :)

After playing around with this, I think I have something that works --- WITH ONE EXCEPTION --- I have not yet successfully used the `rev=` parameter of `dvc.api.get_url()`, so I have no idea how to specify the proper commit. If you can, would you look at my latest edit to my original post? I have shown all my steps, and hopefully you can help me see why I am not using the `rev=` parameter successfully. Thanks for any help/insights here!! You've been very helpful! (P.S., I'm also the ricemcm guy on discord.)

Comment: @Justin I think Saugat from the community has handled this already- `it's a known issue with 2.0 version: https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/5590 The workaround for now is to use file:/// urls in the repo. That way, DVC will clone the repo to read the file.` Please feel free to ping us if get any other issues :)